# How to implement Serial port RS-232 from 2.5V IO signal?

Tags: voltage, fpga, rs232, spartan

I am playing with a Xilinx Spartan-3A development (XC3S50A-TQ144C) and then I tried to implement RS-232 serial port by following the guide here: http://www.fpga4fun.com/SerialInterface.html

I bought a DB-9 port and connect RxD,TxD,GND of DB-9 port to three pin of my development board. (Of coz GND is connect to the GND of my board)

I tried to send a signal of one character every second from the pin to TxD. I checked the signal with a scope. The signal should be correct.

But I cannot see any character shown on my terminal by reading from /dev/ttyS0 (Serial port on Linux).

The scope show that the signal is sent using +2.5V and -2.5V respectively. I think the problem is that serial port should be sent with at least +5V / -5V. How can I modify the board (or construct an amplifier circuit) to send signal in higher voltage?

I have a photo capture of my scope here:

[image]

Comment: Did you verify if the serial port on your PC works?

Comment: I cannot fully confirm as I do not have any serial port hardware now. But I connected RxD to one of my LED in the configuration. When I open /dev/ttyS0, I can see the signal of RxD change. I also tried with another USB to Serial port connector too.

Comment: Have you got Tx (on your dev board) connected to Rx (on your pc)?

Comment: There is no TxD (or serial port) on my development board. They are just custom pin for me to program. I am building a serial port from scratch.

Comment: What RS-232 interface are you using? Have you checked that is working properly?

Comment: @wonghang - you are missing my point - you said "I tried to send a signal of one character every second from the pin to TxD" - have you considered that it should go to Rx?

Comment: @Andyaka you mean I connect it wrongly? I connect pin 3 of DB-9 port to one of my pin to my board (called DB9_3 in my UCF file). I send the signal (as shown in th image) to DB9_3. Am I correct?

Comment: I will try to swap it when I see the board again. Thx for comments

Comment: What RS-232 interface are you using? Have you checked that is working properly?

Comment: Looks like your scope is AC coupled  rather than DC, resulting in false negative voltages as the asymmetric average displays as 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Look up the voltages for RS-232, your 2.5v logic is nowhere close.  5v and sometimes 3.3v logic may work to a degree, but is out of spec.
- RS232 serial is inverted (traditionally in the level translator chip) from the sense of logic level serial.
- if you connected an RS 232 output to your fpga without a level translator you have likely damaged it.
- it is unlikely that you are getting -2.5v out of your fpga, rather this sounds like a measurement or description error.

In summary you need a level translator.

Answer (score 1):

Chris is right, if you want to connect your FPGA to a serial port of any kind, you need to have a proper RS232 driver like the MAX3232 or similar.
Just like this from [Pantech Solutions](http://www.pantechsolutions.net/images/stories/k2-tutorials/detailed-schematic-of-fpga-interface-with-rs232.jpg):

[image]